# How do I get around the "Invalid Token" problem using Prisma Secrets?

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql

I’ve spent several hours scouring forums about how I can avoid the dreaded `Your token is invalid. It might have expired or you might be using a token from a different project.`, but to no avail.

My setup:

- Using `prisma generate` to make a Prisma client and connect it with
- `graphql-yoga` Prisma service running on Heroku
- Prisma service is pointed to an Amazon RDS instance

This setup works when I’m not using the secret property in my `prisma.yml`. However, when I add something like `secret: mysecret` and `prisma deploy` the service, then use something like `prisma playground` to play with the service, I get the above error. This also happens when I manually generate a token using prisma token and use it in an HTTP Authorization header.

What am I missing to make this work?

Comment: I am learning Prisma and Graphql, so no expert. I use node. I use the prisma-binding library. I also added the secret there. I added a reference of prisma into the context of the GraphqlServer. When you add the secret option to prisma.yml, I don't think you can connect to the prisma server directly by the playground. You need to start up the GraphqlServer (graphql-yoga). And use the playground there (default is localhost:4000)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you add the secret to your environment variables. E.g. via a .env file:

```
PRISMA_SECRET="mysecret"
```

When running prisma cli commands make sure to first set the environment variables. E.g. via something like dotenv:

```
dotenv -- prisma admin
```

For more information check out: https://www.prisma.io/docs/prisma-server/authentication-and-security-kke4/#prisma-services